# What benefits do you get from using cascading member functions

Tags: c++, pointers

So I just went over cascading member functions calls by returning the *this pointer. I get how it works mechanically but it looks like a large time investment in implementing the functions for gaining the minor ability to one line chain function calls using the dot operator.  I'm sure there must be some other benefit beyond simply shortening member function calls but there really isn't much information about this subject. The first couple pages of google only came up with instructions on how to implement cascaded function calls and nothing about why, how, or where this technique might be useful. Anyone have some useful links that might cover the subject more indepth? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, that's it, really. Simpler chaining.

Comment: To the people voting to close: How is this not an appropriate question?

Comment: You don't need to do it on all your functions.  But there are some functions where it just makes sense to be able to chain calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The benefit is better-looking code for users of the class when chaining of the operations makes sense. For example:

```
 rect.left( 10 ).top( 5 ).right( 50 ).bottom( 40 );
```

That may be better to read than either:

```
 // longer code
 rect.left( 10 );
 rect.top( 5 );
 rect.right( 50 );
 rect.bottom( 40 );
```

Or:

```
 // reader should remember order of parameters
 rect.move_to( 10, 5, 50, 40 );
```

Answer (score 2):

- Eye-candy code
- Convenient assignment of big amount of items ([Boost Assign library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html))

And sometimes, very rare I guess, but I saw such using (usually in Unit-tests):

- it adds some flexibility with construction of object (you don't have to follow order of arguments or add lots of overloaded constructors)
- it is convenient to represent logic `OR` (for setting flags for example)